# removing arithmetic forms using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to remove ${} among arithmetic form in the file using sed
for example **abc=$(( ${var}+3 ))** to **abc=$(( var+3 ))**

I'm using positional swapping in sed
something like

```
sed -E 's/(\w+\W\$\(\( ) (\$\{) (\w+) (\}) (.*)/\1 \3 \5/g file.txt'
```

but it extracts only **abc=3** when I use

```
echo abc=$((( ${var}+3 )) | sed -E 's/(\w+\W\$\(\( ) (\$\{) (\w+) (\}) (.*)/\1 \3 \5/'
```

in terminal, just to check if it works all right

and it did nothing on shell script how can I remove only ${} part of the file?

I am using Mac OS and also tried on Ubuntu but it was still the same

Comment: Remark: you may need to discriminate keywords. ``$(( ${abc} + 12))`` is, indeed ``$((abc + 12))``. But ``$((${1}+1))`` is not ``$((1+1))``. Or, more convoluted example, ``$(({abc}0+12))`` is not ``$((abc0+12))`` (if abc=15 and abc0=20, first one is 162, second one is 32).

Comment: So, all answer you'll get need some level on assumption on what is and is not in your code. Or must deal with some specific cases. From my examples, you get that the answer you got are not valid if ``$((...))`` expression use positional arguments, or concatenation

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\$\{([^}]*)}/\1/' input_file
abc=$(( var+3 ))
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine, but I thought the result should be only \1 not everything but ${} can you explain why? I must have understood this concept completely wrong

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** Using capturing groups concept here and substituting matched values with captured values and only with which are required please try following `sed` code. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKDWAp/1) for used regex in `sed` code.

```
s='abc=$(( ${var}+3 ))' ##shell variable
sed -E 's/^([^=]*=\$\(\( )\$\{([^}]*)}(.*)$/\1\2\3/' <<<"$s"
```

***OR*** use following in case you have an Input_file from where you want to substitute values.

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^=]*=\$\(\( )\$\{([^}]*)}(.*)$/\1\2\3/' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using Perl's one-liner approach using Lazy match regex to make life easier here, one could try following.

```bash
perl -pe 's/^(.*?)\$\{(.*?)\}(.*)$/$1$2$3/' Input_file
```

Comment: this works perfectly and I understood how it works, but one thing is that first ^, because the file I put in has 2 tabs in front of the string so I thought it shouldn't be detected, can you explain why?

Comment: @mangs, Sorry, could you please do explain it more what's not working and I could try to help you, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf="abc=\$(( \${var}+3 )) to abc=\$(( var+3 ))" | tr -d '{' | tr -d '}'
```